# Can you help me with this Markov Chain question?

Tags: statistics, markov-chains

The Problem: Prove that if the number of States in a Markov Chain is M, and that state j can be reached from state i, then it can be reached in M steps or less.

The work: I assumed by contradiction that state i can reach state j more than M steps. We know that state i can reach to state j with a positive probability.Do I have to do cases in which we assume the Markov chain is irreducible or regular?

To be honest, I have no idea how to start with this proof. Can you guys give me some hints in order for me to understand how to complete this proof?

Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: You can consider the graph associated with your Markov chain. The states are vertices and transition edges in this graph. Then you have to show that there is at least a path shorter than M in between any two connected vertices. Proof by contradiction is going to work.

Answer (score 5):

Let $p_{ij}^{(n)}$ denote the probability that $P(X_n=j|X_0=i)$. We know that $S:=\{n\mid p_{ij}^{(n)}>0\}\neq \emptyset$. We have to show $\min S=M$
Suppose $\min S=k>M$. Then
$p_{ij}^{(k)}>0$. Therefore there exist states $r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_{k-1}$ such that
$$p_{ir_1}p_{r_1r_2}\cdots p_{r_{k-1}j}>0$$
Now among the $k$ steps $r_0:=i,r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_{k-1}$, we must have $r_m=r_n$ for some $m< n$ since $k>M$. But then
$$p_{r_0r_1}\cdots p_{r_{m-1}r_m}p_{r_nr_{n+1}}\cdots p_{r_{k-1}j}>0\implies p_{ij}^{(k-n+m)}>0$$
Therefore $k-n+m\in S$ but $k-n+m<k$. This is a contradiction. Therefore $k\le M$